# Reverse order of a reference to immutable array slice

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I would like to reverse the order of a slice:

```
&[1, 2, 3] -> &[3, 2, 1]
```

This is my code:

```
fn iterate_over_file(data: &[u8], ...) -> ... {
    ...
    for cur_data in data.chunks(chunk_size) {
         let reversed_cur_data = cur_data.reverse() // this returns ()
         ...
    ...
 }
```

This `data` parameter comes from a file I read in using [`FileBuffer`](https://docs.rs/filebuffer/0.1.1/filebuffer/struct.FileBuffer.html), and I'd like to keep it as a referenced slice (and not turn it into an owned `Vec`, since it's a heavy computation to make).

How could I reverse the order of `cur_data` with the minimal amount of operations and memory allocation? Its length is known for a specific runtime of my program (called here `chunk_size`), but it changes between different runs. `reversed()` seems to return `()`, which makes sense as it's done in-place, and I only have a referenced slice. `.iter().rev()` creates an iterator, but then I'd have to call `.next()` on it several times to get the slice back, which is both not elegant and not effective, as I have at least tens of millions of `cur_data` lines per file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not only does `reverse` return `()`, it also requires a mutable slice, which you do not have. The optimal solution depends on exactly what you need to do with the data. If you only need to iterate over the data, `cur_data.iter().rev()` is exactly the right and the most efficient choice.

If you need the reversed data inside a slice for further processing, such as to send the reversed chunk to a function that expects a slice, you can collect the data into a vector. To avoid a new allocation for each chunk, you can reuse the same vector across all loop iterations:

```
let mut reversed = Vec::with_capacity(chunk_size);
for cur_data in data.chunks(chunk_size) {
     // truncate the slice at the beginning of each iteration.
     // Vec explicitly guarantees that this will *not* deallocate,
     // it will only reset its internal length. An allocation will
     // thus only happen prior to the loop.
     reversed.truncate(0);
     reversed.extend(cur_data.iter().rev());
     // &reversed is now the reversed_cur_data you need
     ...
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the difference of `v.extend(iter.rev)` vs `v.extend(iter); v.rev()` would be. The latter *feels* like it cold be more performant.

Comment: @Shepmaster I had the exact opposite feeling :) so I decided to measure. On my machine, [this](https://pastebin.com/MtH0MYd7) takes ~1.02s to execute, while switching to `v.extend(); v.rev()` takes ~1.25s. (Using `extend_from_slice()` makes no difference.) It seems my hunch was correct, at least in the current compiler.

Comment: The measured result makes sense; `v.extend(iter.rev())` reads the data once (in reverse order) and writes it once. On the other hand, `v.extend(iter); v.reverse()` must iterate over the data twice: once to copy it, and then again to reverse it. Ideally `rustc` would figure out what's going on and generate the same code for both (like it already does for `extend_from_slice` vs `extend`), but I guess we're not there yet.